# Copy Paste Site on IIS - Authentication issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis, cookies

I'm working on a MVC .NET project that uses forms authentication. I tried to make a copy of the site and publish it on IIS (different virtual directory). I noticed that I can't get authenticated to the two sites at the same time : when I access one site I automatically get disconnected from the other. What should be changed in order to make it possible to a user to access both of them simultaneously? is it a cookies issue?

I think so, because when I inspect site elements It's obvious that _ASPXAUTH cookie has the same value for both of them. What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a cookies issue?

Yes, most probably. SSO between the 2 websites would very much depend on which domains they are hosted. If they are hosted on 2 sub-domains under the same top level domain such as site1.example.com and site2.example.com all you need to do in order to achieve SSO between them is to set the domain property on the forms authentication cookie to `.example.com` and ensure that both applications share the same machine keys:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms protection="All" domain=".example.com" />
</authentication> 
<machineKey validationKey="XXXXX" decryptionKey="XXX" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

If the 2 sites are on different top level domains such as `example1.com` and `example2.com` then you need much more work to achieve cross domain SSO. You may find some details in [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129123/29407).

---

UPDATE:

I might have misread your question. It appears that you don't want to have SSO between the websites but rather have separate authentication. In this case all you need is to have a different cookie name for both of them:

```
<forms name="SITE1AUTH" />
```

and:

```
<forms name="SITE2AUTH" />
```