# How to set routes in asp.net core for two separate projects in one solution?

Tags: routes, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I created two "asp.net core mvc" projects which work fine separately. Each one has its own routing in their "startup.cs" file when I start them they work well.

My question is :

How to set second project routes from first project?
 Where I should change in first project? What should I add/write?

Example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default_1",
    url: "Project1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default_2",
     url: "Project2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
 UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

This image may help :

[image]

My question is similar to this one but no one answered completely :
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791281/having-separate-projects-in-one-asp-net-mvc-5-solution)

Where is RouteConfig.cs file in vs2017 .net core?

Comment: To clarify are you trying to route from one app to the other?

Comment: @racamp101 Exactly that is what I want to do.

Comment: I have an old project in my solution which works for long time now I want to add another project for doing Native Form as separate project code and different configuration and database

How to set routs from old project for both of them?

Comment: Perhaps they shouldn’t be separate apps if you want to control the routing in one place. What problem are you hoping to solve by separating them?

Comment: they are two separate apps the routing is the same as if the second app was from a completely separate site. Now if your question expands to can i share login and sort like that we need more questions answered. (is it the same domain just subdomains? )

Comment: for your first answer I understood by mistake, I don't want to rout from one app to another I want each of them to have routs seperatlly but define them in old project .

Because when you want use routing only the project which is set as startup is working not the other one

Comment: @racamp101 it is a same domain

Comment: this is a hard question to answer. technically if they are all compatible you can have a common routes class however if they aren't you may need to have more than one place to declare these routes. Could you give more detail into what is the final outcome?

Comment: @tahaGhSa see my answer i believe i got what your asking if its a bit cryptic ill elaborate as needed.

Comment: I am new to this kind of development Sorry if my answers are not helping.

The old project is the website and panel and all things we do for our customers
now we want to add a "form maker" to system which is totally separable that no need to put that in old project as area 

I don't want to put "form maker" project inside old project but I want it to be accessible  by URL and the controllers and methods should be available 

 How to do it this way?
 Is it possible any way?

Comment: @tahaGhSa no apologizes needed just trying to understand we all started new at one time. does my below answer help at all? If it does great! If not please let me know what else you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195429/discussion-between-tahaghsa-and-racamp101).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extension method in a common class library.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

public static IRouteBuilder MapCommonRoutes(this IRouteBuilder routes, string projectRoute)
{
     routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "/" + projectRoute + "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

     // you can add more MapRoute...

     return routes;
 }
```

and use this extension method in startup.cs

For Project 1

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapCommonRoutes("Project1");
});
```

For Project 2

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapCommonRoutes("Project2");
});
```

Comment: thx @sinan how is it working for both projects? which startup.cs should I use  first or second project?

Comment: @tahaGhSa I edited the answer. You can check again. You need to add this method for both projects with the projectRoute parameter. If it's a solution your problem, please mark the answer.

Comment: should I put app.UseMvc ... in startup.cs of each every project ?

Comment: what is the use of MapCommonRoutes method? I can put its code inside of each app.UseMvc ...

Comment: yes, you need to add startup.cs of each project. MapCommonRoutes includes your common route configs. Isn't it good enough for you?

Comment: Bozkus

No I didnt

I don't think if I could do what I want in this way.
As I understood, two projects are not suppose to work along with each other when starting by routes.
I rather to use "Area".

Please correct me If I am wrong.