# ASP.NET Core Routing with 2 Referenced Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I've added a second project to an existing solution and am running into a bit of an issue with routing requests.

When I initially add the second project, there is no problem with routing.

However, I have a DB Context in the original project that I'd like to use from the second.  It is when I add the project reference that my issue manifests.

The issue is that I am getting ambiguous routing requests, so I need to find a way to distinguish requests, for example, to the Home Controller.

Be advised, I use attribute routing.

I've come up with a few workarounds:

- Copy the DB Context into the second project. This has obvious shortcomings and is the least attractive solution, but it will work.
- Set up routes with some distinguishing prefix, i.e. "/proj2Home", etc.  While crude, this is the least objectionable and is straight-forward to implement. It does mandate a route value for every Url of the second project but I could hold my nose on that.
- I've considered using Middleware but it looks like the error is coming from UseRouting() (although I'm not 100% on this) so I'm not sure what I can do at that point.

Does anyone know of some sort of build-in mechanism to accomplish this?

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721530/how-to-set-routes-in-asp-net-core-for-two-separate-projects-in-one-solution) and create an extension method in a common class library to set routing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I mentioned, I use attribute routing, so this technique won't work.